# C#: What is the proper data structure? (jagged object "array")

Tags: c#, data-structures, jagged-arrays

I have a `List`  of `IWord` objects named `taggedInput`.
I need to associate each element with its own `List` of `IWord` objects. 
For this I need to use a different datatype.

In this datatype, both the parent list and the child list must be dynamic, and must be populated at run-time.

The parent list must allow duplicate values (so it cannot be a `Dictionary` object).

I intend to iterate through the parent list, and manipulate (add, remove, reorganize) the elements in the child list. Each element in both the parent and child lists must be accessible by its position in the list.

Here is an image I made to better illustrate what I need:

[image]

What is the best data type to use for this? I need something like `List<IWord,List<IWord>>` 
(but that wouldn't be a list)

Comment: Try a Tuple<T1, T2> which is just a data structure with 2 properties, T1 and T2. These are built in with .NET 4, but have to be manually made in anything below

Comment: @PostMan Ah ok great, that looks like a solution. This is what you mean, right?
new List < Tuple<IWord, List<IWord>>>();

Comment: @nunespascal Just because its 2d. Im just saying that List<IWord> is unsatisfactory on its own, and List<IWord,List<IWord>> is not a valid structure.

Comment: create a custom class named `class WordList : List<IWord> { ... }` and add a property to it named `List<IWord> Children { get; private set; }` and create a list of WordList - `List<WordList>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you cannot change the `IWord` interface? In that case I would use another type to allow you to form the required relationship ...

```
public class WordWithRelatives
{
   public IWord Word {get;set;}
   public List<IWord> Relatives {get;set;}
}
```

Then you simply require a list of the above

```
var taggedInput = List<WordWithRelatives>();
```

You could also make `WordWithRelatives` implement `IWord` by forwarding the `IWord` interface methods to the `Word` instance it contains.